# Microsoft API Graph create distribution list

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I try to create a distribution list on Office365 with the Microsoft API Graph.

For that, I do a POST request on "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/blih.bocal.org/groups" with json parameters :

```
{
    "description": "My description",
    "displayName": "testlist",
    "groupTypes": ['Unified'],
    "mailEnabled": True,
    "mailNickname": "testlist",
    "securityEnabled": False  
}
```

It creates an office365 group or a security group with some little changes, but impossible to create a distribution list. Via the web, I can do it and when I get it with the API, the parameter "groupTypes" is empty.

What's bad on my request or how to do it (if it's possible) ?

Answer (score 0):

http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/group_post_groups

You can create Unified Group or Security Group or Dynamic Group alone with this API. Refer the documentation in the above URL.

Comment: Yes, you can't create DL with Microsoft Graph API.